# Is a High Elf's cantrip innate or is it learned?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, racial-traits, cantrips, elf

Where does a High Elf get their Wizard cantrip? Is it innate? If innate, is it hereditary (so that an Elf would have the same cantrip as one of its parents, and share it with siblings)? Or is just the ability to cast *a* cantrip innate, and the one they have is just the one they have a natural affinity for?

Or is the cantrip learned, so that it's more akin to their Elf Weapon Training, and they have been trained to cast a certain cantrip?

In other words, are High Elves innately magical like Drow are, or does the cantrip come from their society place a large emphasis on learning magic?

Answer (score 19):

## High Elves most likely learn their cantrip.

Per the High Elf's Cantrip trait description (PHB 5e),

> You know one cantrip of your choice from the wizard spell list. Intelligence is your spellcasting ability for it.

Per Using Each Ability, Intelligence (PHB 5e),

> Intelligence measures mental acuity, accuracy of recall, and the ability to reason.

Based on this, High Elves have studied their cantrip. If it were innate, we could expect them to gain a Sorcerer cantrip instead, or use Wisdom or Charisma for their spellcasting ability. In addition, choosing a Wizard cantrip could imply that the cantrip is learned, since Wizards gain their spell through rigorous study.

Of course, this is usually up to DM discretion.

Answer (score 14):

Consider the wording of the description of a High Elf in the Player's Handbook.

> As a high elf, you have a keen mind and a **mastery** of at least the basics of magic.

Emphasis Mine

Compare to a Drow, who (per the MM) are listed to have 'Innate' magic.

Mastery is defined as...

> possession or display of great skill or technique

Innate as...

> existing in, belonging to, or determined by factors present in an individual from birth

Both from the Mirriam-Webster dictionary.

Mastery of magic implies something learned...a skill you have developed. Innate implies it is something you're simply born with.

So, High Elves have studied the 'basics of magic' along with the traditional elvish weapons. Their cantrip is learned, not natural.